# How to pick an exact element from HashMap using Java8

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap

I need to pick an exact element from a hash map.

I wrote a method that should return an element. 
From line:

```
this.referenceEntityCache.getReferenceEntities();
```

I will receive a `hashMap` looking like this **Map** :

```
         {[Element: <Ry/>] = EntityTree@1,
        // [Element: <Nd/>] = EntityTree@2,
        // [Element: <Ry/>] = EntityTree@3,
        // [Element: <Ah/>] = EntityTree@4,
        // [Element: <Ah/>] = EntityTree@5 }
```

and from this map I need to get only the "Ah" element.
The hashMap has the key = Element :   and value of entityTree linked to it.

```
public Element pickUpTheElement() {
    Element ahElement = null;
    Map<Element, EntityTree> mapOfElements = this.referenceEntityCache.getReferenceEntities();
    return ahElement = mapOfElements.map(map -> map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(e -> Objects.equals(e.getValue(), element))
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .findAny());
                .orElse(null);
```

have no idea how to filter it properly using Java8 and obtain only "Ah" Element from it. There are 2 element of Ah - but as they are objects - they have different hashcodes since their values (EntityTree) are different

Comment: You sure that this is your hashmap?

Comment: To support @JokaLee , what does the `Element` and its `equals` implementation look like? Since it mostly seems you are having 2 same keys in your Map, which is not quite feasible or else the representation would have been grouped as `Map<Element, List<EntityTree>>` or similar. Other few aspects that wouldn't work with the code shared `mapOfElements.map`, `return ah = mapOf...`

Comment: Define 'pick an exact element'.

Comment: strange name and convention `Objects.equals(e.getValue(), element)` where the value actually is an `EntityTree` and not sure what `element` is... and then *I cannot initialize `Element element = null`, because of Optional type* is completely unclear in the question.

Comment: 1) you are trying to invoke a non-existing method `map` on a `Map`. 2) You are referencing two variables, `ah` and `element`, which are nowhere defined in your code example 3) on the other hand, the variable `ahElement` is entirely unused 4) Your problem description, “I cannot initialize `Element element = null`”, refers again to the variable not declared in your code and it’s unclear why you want to initialize that variable to `null`

Answer (score 1):

You can return `null` as default value (if the `Optional` is empty):

```
return mapOfElements.entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(e -> Objects.equals(e.getValue(), element))
                    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                    .findAny()
                    .orElse(null);
```

Comment: does his map in question makes sense?

Comment: @JokaLee makes sense to whom?